# postgres delete from indirectly related tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have TableA that can have many TableB related to it and TableB can have many TableC rows related to it which TableC has many TableD rows. So TableA -> TableB -> TableC -> TableD. What I want to do is given the TableA row id, select all the TableD rows that are related through other tables and delete all of them.

```
TableA   |   TableB |   TableC |   TableD
--------------------------------------
tableAId | tableAId | tableBId | tableCId

         | tableBId | tableCId | tableDId
```

and the query i've tried:

```
DELETE FROM TableD
 WHERE TableA.tableAId = 2
 AND TableA.tableAId= TableB.tableAId
 AND TableB.tableBId= TableC.tableBId
 AND TableC.tableCId = TableD.tableCId
```

sample table

```
TableA        TableB                     TableC                TableD

tableAID | tableAID  tableBId | tableBId   tableCId | tableCId   tableDId
---------|--------------------|---------------------|---------------------
 1       | 1            15    |  15         5       | 6              4
 2       | 2           16     |  16         6       | 5              3
                                                      5              14
                                                      5              11
```

Desired result, Given tableAId = 1

```
TableA        TableB                     TableC                TableD

tableAID | tableAID  tableBId | tableBId   tableCId | tableCId   tableDId
---------|--------------------|---------------------|---------------------
 1       | 1            15    |  15         5       | 6              4
 2       | 2           16     |  16         6       |
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: added sample and desired results, hope it makes sense

Comment: Your query almost done. Just add to it the list of using tables: `DELETE FROM TableD USING TableA, TableB, TableC WHERE ...` More about `USING` clause in the documentation: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-delete.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this,

```
DELETE
FROM TableD AS inner
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT
  FROM tableD AS outer
  JOIN tableC
    USING (tableDid)
  JOIN tableB
    USING (tableBid)
  JOIN tableA
    USING (tableAid)
  WHERE tableAId = 2
   AND outer.tableDid = inner.tableDid
);
```

Comment: That worked, just had to change the inner and outer names and where you had `USING (tableDid)` shoulda be `USING (tableCid)`

Comment: Don't you need to quote `"outer"`  as it is a reserved keyword?

Answer (score 1):

Use the following subquery to get all `tableCId`s that are related to your given `tableAId`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TableC.tableCId
FROM TableC
LEFT JOIN TableB ON TableC.tableBId = TableB.tableBId
WHERE TableB.tableAId = 2
```

You can now use this subquery in your delete command, which should work somehow like this:

```
DELETE FROM tableD
USING ( ... ) sub
WHERE tableD.tableCId IN (SELECT * FROM sub)
```